# How to refresh default display option in select by javascript or jquery if there is more than one select fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I've got a problem, I know how to change the selection when I have one select field, but what if there is two of them? 
For one select field I use this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sNhb6/1/ 
but i can't make it work with two select fields. For example:

```
 <select id="select1">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
 <select id="select2">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

When I write 
`$("select").val("2");` 
 It's changing value of all fields. 
I've tried 
`$('select2').val("B");`
 but it's not working at all.

What can I do in that case? Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

`$("#select1").val("2");`

`$("#select2").val("B");`

Please note the `#` ID Selector.

Answer (score 2):

use this 
$("#select2").val("sometext");